# What are the steps to create AJAX login in yiiframework?

Tags: ajax, authentication, yii

I just started learning AJAX and Yiiframework. What are the steps to create AJAX login form in Yii?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in your view, where the login button is

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxButton('Add Course', array('student_Courses/Create'),array(
        'type'=>'POST',
        'update'=>'#resultStudentCourse',
        'beforeSend' => 'function(){
            $("#resultStudentCourse").addClass("loading");
        }',
        'complete' => 'function(){
            $("#resultStudentCourse").removeClass("loading");
            }',

)); ?>
```

`#resultStudentCourse` is the ID of the DIV where you need to load in your message, EG. Successfully logged-in

Then in your controller the create method have something like this

```
if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){
$this->renderPatial('create',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){
$this->renderPatial('create',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

For the sake of real clarity (as not too many folks are using this framework quite yet) the above should be

```
$this->renderPartial
```